# Youtube Analytics API - Is the View report restricted to 200 videos?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to find out if I can create a custom report using the Youtube Analytics API that will a) give me the total number of lifetime views (or custom date range) for a channel, and b) give me a full list of all videos belonging to a Youtube channel along with the number of views for each video.

For the first point I know I can get 'Views' via the 'Basic Stats' report, but information here - https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1714329?ref_topic=1714326&guide=1714169 - claims that the Views report only gives views for the top 200 videos belonging to a channel.

Does the 200 max relate to the YT dashboard only, or does it also relate to the API? In short will this report give me views for all videos, above and beyond 200?

For the second point, I know the 'Top Videos' report has a maximum of 10, so does that mean to get an aggregate view of all top videos belonging to a channel I will need to run a 'basic stats' report for every video individually?

For reference - https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while since you asked this question. If you haven't resolved it yet,

1) I believe the dashboard can show you all the videos but the API limits to 200 videos.

2) To get all the videos belong to a channel and views of each video.

```
Get Upload ID from channels.list
Get the list of all videos from playlist_items.list by passing in the Upload_ID
```

Please keep in mind that, max results for playlist_items.list is 50 per page (maxResults => 50). And each call returns the nextPageToken which use can use for pagination.